# Explain الموقع فايلات اكسيل noun phrase in Arabic

Tags: arabic, nouns

I have the following Arabic sentence and I am interested in the last three words which create a noun phrase. This np is translated as "Site Vaalat Excel" by google, which does not tell me much.

```
  ارجو ان تكون الفواتير على الموقع فايلات اكسيل
```

What I want to know is what is the main/head word in "الموقع فايلات اكسيل" noun phrase? 
For example in English it would be like this "Vaalat Excel site", so the main word would be "site" with "Vaalat" and "Excel" being attributes to this word. What about Arabic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read Arabic the first rule is to forget about google translate. It is useless. الموقع is Arabic for “the place”, here in the sense “site”. فايلات is the English word “file” with the Arabic plural ending –āt. The last word is the brand name “Excel” written in Arabic script. Syntactically, fāylāt eksel is a possessive phrase (ʼiḍāfa), literally “files of Excel”. This phrase is in apposition (badal) to al-mawqiʽ.

Comment: الموقع  also can refer to a website/page!